# Correct sql query to return null when optional FK row doesn't exists for PK row (1 to none/many)

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join, table-alias

What is the correct way to write this query for mysql (this one seems to work, but seems idiotic) (191 is hard code for a variable)

```
select t1.item_id, t1.item_name, t1.item_desc, t.quantity, t.price 
from (select * from items i where i.item_id = 191) as T1
LEFT JOIN (select * from item_properties ip) as T
on t1.item_id = t.fk_item_id and t1.item_id=191;
```

T1.item_id is PK, T.fk_item_id is foreign key (? -- only can exist if parent T1.item_id exists)

This was my way of returning t.values as null when they don't exist (and can't be joined).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    i.item_id, i.item_name, i.idem_desc,
    p.quantity, p.price
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN item_properties p ON i.item_id = p.fk_item_id
WHERE i.item_id = 191
```

Left join is required so rows from left table are always returned, even when there are no matching row in the right table. But those SELECT in the FROM were not necessary. Try to keep things simple when they are.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read how to implement joins correctly in mysql, [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

and if you want result only if matches in both tables use inner join for FK and PK

Comment: My perceived problem is that I'm not sure if FK row exists ... so attempt on inner join with non-existent FK excludes the PK results.

Comment: can u please edit your question show your table structure and expected result like this , click on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216872/select-query-is-not-working-using-mysql  edit your question so we can understand actually what you need