# Select query is not working using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with sale and receipt

Tables structure and result table structure are given below.

**sale**

```
date        |   total
------------+-----------
2014-08-09  |  500
2014-07-08  |   50
2014-07-08  |  100
```

**receipt**

```
date        |    net_amount   
----------- +-----------------
2014-08-08  |      50
2014-08-08  |      50
```

**Expected Result**

```
month     total      net_amount
-------+----------+---------------
07     |   150    |
08     |   500    |    100
```

**QUERY**

```
select MONTH(date),total,net_amount from (
select MONTH(date) as month,
sum(total) as total 2 as sort_col from
sale union all select MONTH(date) as month, 
sum(net_amount) as net_amount, 
1 as sort_col from receipt) 
as a order by MONTH(date) desc, sort_col desc
```

Comment: Can you please add the output you're expecting to get for this data? I'm not sure I'm following the question.

Comment: i gave result table structure in the above,plzz check it

Comment: sum of total and net_amount month wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 select Month(date),sum(total),sum(net_amount)
 from (
 select date,sum(total) as total,0 as net_amount from sale group by month(date)
 union all 
 select date, 0 as total,sum(net_amount) from receipt group by month(date)) 
 as tabl group by Month(date)
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4360d8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    s.`month`, total, net_amount
FROM      (SELECT   MONTH(sale.`date`) AS `month`, 
                    SUM(total) AS total
           FROM     sale
           GROUP BY MONTH(sale.`date`)) s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   MONTH(receipt.`date`) AS `month`, 
                    SUM(net_amount) AS net_amount
           FROM     receipt
           GROUP BY MONTH(receipt.`date`)) r ON s.`month` = s.`month`
```

Comment: shows the error #1052 - Column 'total' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @user3901574 copy-paste bug. The alias in the second subquery should have been `net_amount` - fixed.